# System of coset representatives

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H$ be a subgroup of finite index in the group $G$. We use $g\in G/H$ as notation for $g\in R$,
 where $R$ is a complete set of representatives for $G/H.$

1. Proof or disproof: If $g\in G/H$ runs over a complete set of representatives for $G/H$, then also $g^{-1}$ runs over a complete set of representatives for $G/H$.
2. If (1) not true, what is the minimum conditions we need to assume to make (1) true.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x,y\in R\implies\left(xH=yH\iff y^{-1}x\in H\right)$$

$$x,y\in R\implies\left(x^{-1}H=y^{-1}H\iff xy^{-1}\in H\right)$$

Thus, if $\;G\;$ is abelian then the claim is true: $\;y^{-1}x=xy^{-1}\;$

Counterexample if $\;G\;$ is not abelian:

$$G:=S_4\;,\;\;H:=\{\sigma\in S_4\;;\;\sigma(1)=1\}\cong S_3\;,\;\;R=\{(1),(12),(132),(14)\}$$

Note that $\;|S_4|=24\;,\;\;|H|=6\;,\;\;[G:H]=4\;$. I'll leave it to you to show $\;R\;$ indeed is a full set of representatives of the left cosets of $\;H\;$, but $\;R^{-1}=\{(1),(12),(14),(123)\}\;$ is not (hint: check that $\;(123)\;$ thing...)

Comment: A weaker condition that would make (1) true is that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. That might be the answer they want!

Comment: @DerekHolt, good point.I think you're right.